# How to define the pass-in parameter for the __init__ in Cython

Tags: python, cython

https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/cython-docs2/stable/cython-docs2.pdf
page: 9/47

```
cimport cqueue

cdef class Queue:
  cdef cqueue.Queue _c_queue

  def __cinit__(self):
    self._c_queue = cqueue.queue_new()
    if self._c_queue is NULL:
      raise MemoryError()

  def __init__(self, name): # I added this section
    self.name = name # Queue' object has no attribute 'name'
```

After I build the file and use `q = Queue('hello')`, the compiler always gives me error as

> 'Queue' object has no attribute 'name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing a bracket on the `__init__` line but I don't think that's the real issue ( - now fixed in an edit)

Your problem is that [Cython classes don't have a dictionary by default](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/extension_types.html#attributes), so you can only add attributes that you have predefined. Therefore you need to tell it that the class has an attribute called `name`:

```
cdef class Queue:
  cdef cqueue.Queue _c_queue
  cdef name # not specifying a type makes it a Python object
  # ...
```

You may want to make `name` `cdef public` so it's accessible from Python too.

As an alternative, you can give the class a dictionary, and that should allow arbitrary attributes to be set at the cost of slower access and a larger object:

```
cdef class Queue
  cdef cqueue.Queue _c_queue
  cdef dict __dict__
  # ...
```

This seems to require a reasonably recent (last year or so) version of Cython to work.